# Error parsing data when drawing d3 line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to draw a difference chart ([like this one](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3894205)) but using a more modular style.

So far, I've got as far as reading in two dummy CSV files, combining the data, generating a chart, and am now trying to just draw a single line from one part of the data, but I keep getting an error. [The full code is available on bl.ocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org/philgyford/10247700).

The error is:

> Error: Problem parsing d="M0,221.73913043478262LNaN,182.60869565217394LNaN,195.6521739130435LNaN,156.52173913043478L500,91.30434782608697L500,91.30434782608697LNaN,156.52173913043478LNaN,195.6521739130435LNaN,182.60869565217394L0,221.73913043478262Z"

which occurs when doing this:

```
g.select('.line').attr('d', line);
```

At that point (as seen in the console), `data` is:

```
[{"year":1999,"imports":15,"exports":19},{"year":2000,"imports":18,"exports":20},{"year":2001,"imports":17,"exports":30},{"year":2002,"imports":20,"exports":32},{"year":2003,"imports":25,"exports":9}]
```

`xScale.range()` is:

```
[0, 500]
```

`xScale.domain()` is:

```
[1999, 2003]
```

`yScale.range()` is:

```
[300, 0]
```

and `yScale.domain()` is:

```
[9, 32]
```

I'm guessing there's a simple error somewhere in there, meaning the wrong data is being used to draw the line, but after several hours trying to fix this, I can't see what I've done wrong.

Comment: Seems like those NaN values in your path data are the root of your problem. Probably there's something wrong with the `Y()` function. But tell the exact problem without putting more time into it. Care to set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look Khôi, but Lars found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an ordinal scale, which doesn't interpolate between values. The domain of that scale consists of two elements, and it will map those to the two elements in the output range. That is, 1999 is mapped to 0 and 2003 is mapped to 500. For any other inputs, the scale will return NaN as the value isn't in its input domain.

You can fix this by specifying all the years you want mapped in the domain and the corresponding output values in the range. In your case, the easiest would be to use a linear scale though as that seems to be what you're assuming will happen with your current scale. You would simply need to replace the definition of the scale and how the range is set. This is what I have done [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/10249919).

Alternatively, you could use a time scale as that would give you potentially better labels.

Comment: So simple when you know how, thank you Lars! For some reason I always think the domain is the min and max values, and didn't realise it was different for ordinal scales. Thanks again for your time.